# How to use Quarkus Projections to load value into DTO with List/Set and other DTO?

Tags: quarkus

This link (https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-reactive-panache#query-projection) contains sample for projecting values into DTO primitive data type fields.

But how do you load value into List object or another POJO/DTO using Quarkus Projections?

Example:

```
    public class User {
        private String name;
    }
    public class Comment {
        private String text;
        private Date createdAt;
    }
    public class Post {
        private String text;
        private User author;
        private List comments;
    }
```

From the sample above, how to do set value of Post.author and Post.comments using Quarkus projections?

Can this be achieved using Hibernate? Or is there a Quarkus specific solution?

Comment: Keep reading the same paragraph until you reach the section about @ ProjectedFieldName.

Comment: I did the following:
`
    public class dto.Post {
        ...
        private List<dto.Comment> comments;
        public Post(String text, @ProjectedFieldName("comments") List<dto.Comment> comments) {
        ...
            this.comments = comments;
        }
    }
`
Then:
repository.find("SELECT p.text, p.comments.* FROM entity.Post p").project(dto.Post.class).list();

And I am getting the following error:
org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: A query exception occurred [select new dto.Post(rp.text, p.comments.*) FROM dto.Post p]

Comment: Can Quarkus Query Projections do something Hibernate is doing from this link: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-select-clause